# Pass Json object to other class method

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I'm trying to pass json decoded object to method of a class. But when I try to access properties of that object, it gives notice: Trying to get property of non-object php. But when I write that object variable to a file it shows all data.

I'm trying to update hubspot data using its api when a webhook event is sent by memberpress plugin.

Here is what i'm doing:

**File: hubspotsync.php**

```
require_once 'class-synchronize.php';

class HubspotSync{

public function init()
{
    $encoded_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
    if( $encoded_data != '' ){
        $data = json_decode($encoded_data);
        $this->perform_action($data);
    }


}

private function perform_action($data)
{
    $synchronize    = new Synchronize();
    $synchronize->perform_sync($data);
    unset($synchronize);
}


}
$sync = new HubspotSync();
$sync->init();
unset($sync);
```

**File : class-syncronize.php**

```
class Synchronize{


    public function perform_sync($eventobj)
    {
      // If I fwrite this $eventObj to a file, it looks like as below. but gives an notice on next code. why???

      $event_type = $eventobj->event; // This line gives the notice.
    }

}
```

**$eventobj looks like this:**

```
    stdClass Object
(
    [event] => subscription-created
    [type] => subscription
    [data] => stdClass Object
        (
            [coupon] => 
            [membership] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 16
                    [title] => Monthly Subscription
                    [content] => 
                    [excerpt] => 
                    [date] => 2016-09-16 19:22:07
                    [status] => publish
                    [author] => 4
                    [date_gmt] => 2016-09-16 19:22:07
                    [modified] => 2017-09-27 15:19:04
                    [modified_gmt] => 2017-09-27 20:19:04
                    [group] => 0
                    [price] => 28.00
                    [period] => 1
                    [period_type] => months
                    [signup_button_text] => Sign Up
                    [limit_cycles] => 
                    [limit_cycles_num] => 2
                    [limit_cycles_action] => expire
                    [trial] => 
                    [trial_days] => 0
                    [trial_amount] => 0.00
                    [trial_once] => 1
                    [group_order] => 0
                    [is_highlighted] => 
                    [pricing_title] => Monthly Subscription
                    [pricing_show_price] => 1
                    [pricing_display] => auto
                    [custom_price] => 
                    [pricing_heading_txt] => 
                    [pricing_footer_txt] => 
                    [pricing_button_txt] => Sign Up
                    [pricing_button_position] => footer
                    [pricing_benefits] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [register_price_action] => default
                    [register_price] => 
                    [thank_you_page_enabled] => 1
                    [thank_you_message] => Thank you for signing up for a monthly subscription to The Prudent Speculator. Please contact info@theprudentspeculator.com with any questions regarding your subscription. Your login credentials should be e-mailed to you shortly.
                    [custom_login_urls_enabled] => 
                    [custom_login_urls_default] => 
                    [custom_login_urls] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [expire_type] => delay
                    [expire_after] => 1
                    [expire_unit] => days
                    [expire_fixed] => 2017-09-27
                    [tax_exempt] => 
                    [allow_renewal] => 
                    [access_url] => 
                    [disable_address_fields] => 
                    [simultaneous_subscriptions] => 
                    [use_custom_template] => 
                    [custom_template] => custom/page-archive.php
                    [customize_payment_methods] => 1
                    [custom_payment_methods] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => owyg62-7fu
                        )

                    [customize_profile_fields] => 1
                    [custom_profile_fields] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => mepr_phone
                            [1] => mepr_username
                        )

                    [cannot_purchase_message] => You don't have access to purchase this item.
                )

            [member] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 25
                    [email] => craig.andrews@allies4me.com
                    [username] => craigandrews
                    [nicename] => craigandrews
                    [url] => 
                    [message] => 
                    [registered_at] => 2017-10-16 20:56:16
                    [ip] => 24.27.9.104
                    [first_name] => Craig
                    [last_name] => Andrews
                    [display_name] => craigandrews
                )

            [id] => 7
            [subscr_id] => mp-sub-59e7cdb3d47e0
            [response] => 
            [gateway] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => PayPal Payments Pro
                    [label] => Paypal
                    [use_label] => 1
                    [icon] => https://prudent2.wpengine.com/wp-content/plugins/memberpress/images/checkout/cards.png
                    [use_icon] => 1
                    [desc] => Pay with your credit card via PayPal
                    [use_desc] => 1
                    [id] => owyg62-7fu
                    [settings] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [gateway] => MeprPayPalProGateway
                            [id] => owyg62-7fu
                            [label] => Paypal
                            [use_label] => 1
                            [icon] => https://prudent2.wpengine.com/wp-content/plugins/memberpress/images/checkout/cards.png
                            [use_icon] => 1
                            [desc] => Pay with your credit card via PayPal
                            [use_desc] => 1
                            [api_username] => kbroughton_api1.afamcapital.com
                            [api_password] => 48UDEBHJBB6RXNVY
                            [signature] => AQUF7rVduRDHYM-3AIBZaDFk-4ZYAZQgmcG7B9LdUmyA7fRkA9Mk1gPj
                            [sandbox] => on
                            [force_ssl] => on
                            [debug] => 
                            [saved] => 1
                            [url] => https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
                            [api_url] => https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp
                            [api_version] => 69
                        )

                    [capabilities] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => process-payments
                            [1] => process-refunds
                            [2] => create-subscriptions
                            [3] => cancel-subscriptions
                            [4] => update-subscriptions
                            [5] => suspend-subscriptions
                            [6] => resume-subscriptions
                            [7] => subscription-trial-payment
                        )

                )

            [ip_addr] => 70.112.70.86
            [price] => 28.00
            [period] => 1
            [period_type] => months
            [limit_cycles] => 0
            [limit_cycles_num] => 2
            [limit_cycles_action] => expire
            [prorated_trial] => 0
            [trial] => 0
            [trial_days] => 0
            [trial_amount] => 0.00
            [status] => pending
            [created_at] => 2017-10-18 21:54:59
            [total] => 28.00
            [tax_rate] => 0.000
            [tax_amount] => 0.00
            [tax_desc] => 
            [tax_class] => standard
            [cc_last4] => 
            [cc_exp_month] => 
            [cc_exp_year] => 
            [token] => 
            [tax_compound] => 0
            [tax_shipping] => 1
        )

)
```

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong here.

Comment: @deceze Exactly what I'm thinking, then why it gives me an notice. Its not returning a value to $event_type variable. Since this data is posted by the webhook, does that have to do something with it?

Comment: `var_dump` the variable straight to screen. Test the webhook by calling it yourself with the expected data. Debug more.

Comment: @deceze since the webhook post data on a php file url, I'm not able/dont know to var_dump response when the webhook has been executed. Because of that I write down the variable to file and check its value.

Answer (score 0):

`var_dump( $eventObj )` and make sure that the `event` property actually exists on that object. It might be `$eventObj['event']` or something weird like that. The error is telling you that `event` doesnt exist on your `$eventObj`